# Symfony sub-form and entity initialization

Tags: php, forms, symfony, constructor

Let's say I have an entity `User`, with a OneToOne relation called `friends` with targetEntity `Friend`.

I have a class `UserType` to build my form, which adds a field friends, building a subform with a `FriendType` class.

Both my entities have a constructor so I can initialize some of their fields.
When I create my form (on creation, not on update), the **constructor is called only for the User entity, not for Friend**.

Is this a normal behaviour? Is there an option that could force the entity Friend to be instanciated before submit?

**UPDATE**

I eventually realized this is a normal behavior indeed. Underlying entities for nested forms are **NOT** initialized with their constructor. Simplest solution is to set a new Friend to User before passing the entity User to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the User don't have any friend yet. In your controller when the user entity is created you must set the new Friend before the UserType is created , or in the user constructor you can call the new Friend constructor. Also depending of what you need it's possible to initialize a friend entity on prePersist event on users with a listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it would work, but it doesn't.
I'm setting a new friend in the User's constructor, but the form doesn't use it to populates its fields, there must be a bug in my code?? That's strange, the form retrieves the data all right on update.
I'm also wondering what to do with oneToMany relations. I have a few, set with a CollectionType, and I can't know how many I should "pre-instanciate". I might use a listener in the formbuilder.
I really hoped there would be a way to force the form to create the underlying entity before submit, but it doesn't look so.

Comment: I usually do this kind of things in the controller and I'm sure that it work. Has you tried set the friend before user type creation?

Comment: I've tried to initialize the entity in the controller, just before passing it to the forrmBuilder, and it doesn't work either. When I dump the entity, the field is correctly set, and appears on a line saying :` -criminalRecord: CriminalRecord {#528 ▶}` 
But at the end of the field's list, there's an extra field starting with a + sign, saying `+"setCriminalRecord": CriminalRecord {#527 ▶}` and this one is not initialized.